# How do I extract the code in-between using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the text 'THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT' from the snippet below. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

```html
<span class="cw-type__h2 Ingredients-title">Ingredients</span>
<p>
                                THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<span class="cw-type__h2 Ingredients-title">Ingredients</span><p>THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.p.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is likely more html, I would use the class of the preceeding `span` with [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and `p` type selector to target the appropriate `p` tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<span class="cw-type__h2 Ingredients-title">Ingredients</span>
<p>
                                THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT</p>
                                '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.Ingredients-title + p').text.strip())
```